# Unable to correctly use .setLayoutParams(...) - Android

Tags: java, android, layout, android-linearlayout

I wanted to try using a database on Android, so I made a small app that allows you to add contacts to the database and then it displays them.

I have been able to display contacts (from the database) if I create the layout in XML and then edit the text field in code. But I wanted to build the layouts in code so I can add as many contacts as I want.

The following code is the method I use to create the layout and the app crashes whenever I make it run this code. My guess is that there is a problem with the parameters. If only type LayoutParams.MatchContent, it asks me to import and it gives me many options, and that’s why it says LinearLayout.LayoutParams...;

I add the resulting layout to a LinearLayout.

```java
private LinearLayout createContactView (Contact contact) {
    LinearLayout contactInfoWrapper = new LinearLayout(this);
    contactInfoWrapper.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    contactInfoWrapper.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView nameView = new TextView(this);
    nameView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    nameView.setText(contact.getName());
    contactInfoWrapper.addView(nameView);

    TextView numberView = new TextView(this);
    numberView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    numberView.setText(contact.getPhoneNumber());
    contactInfoWrapper.addView(numberView);

    return contactInfoWrapper;
}
```

Comment: stack trace please

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `setLayoutParams`, use the `LayoutParams` in the `addView(View v, LayoutParams params)` method of your `LinearLayout`:

```
TextView nameView = new TextView(this);
nameView.setText(contact.getName());
contactInfoWrapper.addView(nameView, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: did what you said for both text views and for the linear layout and the issue is still there

Comment: I completely misread the question. You wrote that your app **crashes**. What is the stacktrace? (edit your question with it)

Comment: omg thanks. I had never thought of even looking for the stacktrace since I never used it (I'm new to android). I initialized the LinearLayout (a global variable) locally so when i tried to use it on a seperate method it resulted on a NullPointerException. nothing to do with the parameters aparently.

Comment: Looks like you solved your error. You should write it as an answer and accept it when you are able to.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
numberView.setText(contact.getPhoneNumber());
```

to this:

```
numberView.setText(String.valueOf(contact.getPhoneNumber()));
```

Comment: The phoneNumber is a String